# socket.emit within collection.find.each problem

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, socket.io

Im trying to send a socket.emit for each document I get from a capped tailable connection.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A new user has joined!');
    socket.emit('message', { message: 'A new user has joined!' });

    mongo.MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, client) {
        const db = client.db('sds');
        db.collection('messages', function(err, collection) {
            const doc = collection
                .find({}, { tailable: true, awaitdata: true, numberOfRetries: -1 })
                .each(function(err, doc) {
                    console.log(doc._id);
                    socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify(doc));
                });
        });
    });
});
```

The console output looks like this. Why are there multiple new connections? I have only opened one session from the browser. Also after iterating through the docs in the collectoin,I expected to wait for new being inserted. But it continues over again with what seems to be random new connectoins. Can async/await help solve the repeated docs?

```
A new user has joined!
A new user has joined!
A new user has joined!
A new user has joined!
5e8f778de9913c3fb2524ca1
5e8f77bae9913c3fb2524ca2
5e8f7875e9913c3fb2524ca3
5e8f787ae9913c3fb2524ca4
5e8f7940e9913c3fb2524ca5
5e8f7945e9913c3fb2524ca6
5e8f85f5eface4446ad22726
5e8f85faeface4446ad22727
5e8f874feface4446ad22728
5e8f778de9913c3fb2524ca1
5e8f77bae9913c3fb2524ca2
5e8f7875e9913c3fb2524ca3
5e8f787ae9913c3fb2524ca4
5e8f7940e9913c3fb2524ca5
5e8f7945e9913c3fb2524ca6
5e8f85f5eface4446ad22726
5e8f85faeface4446ad22727
5e8f874feface4446ad22728
A new user has joined!
5e8f778de9913c3fb2524ca1
5e8f77bae9913c3fb2524ca2
5e8f7875e9913c3fb2524ca3
5e8f787ae9913c3fb2524ca4
5e8f7940e9913c3fb2524ca5
5e8f7945e9913c3fb2524ca6
5e8f85f5eface4446ad22726
5e8f85faeface4446ad22727
5e8f874feface4446ad22728
5e8f778de9913c3fb2524ca1
5e8f77bae9913c3fb2524ca2
5e8f7875e9913c3fb2524ca3
5e8f787ae9913c3fb2524ca4
5e8f7940e9913c3fb2524ca5
5e8f7945e9913c3fb2524ca6
5e8f85f5eface4446ad22726
5e8f85faeface4446ad22727
5e8f874feface4446ad22728
5e8f778de9913c3fb2524ca1
5e8f77bae9913c3fb2524ca2
5e8f7875e9913c3fb2524ca3
5e8f787ae9913c3fb2524ca4
5e8f7940e9913c3fb2524ca5
5e8f7945e9913c3fb2524ca6
5e8f85f5eface4446ad22726
5e8f85faeface4446ad22727
5e8f874feface4446ad22728
A new user has joined!
...
```

Comment: Some possibilities here: [socket.io repeats io.on('connection', ...) over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030515/node-js-socket-io-repeats-the-io-onconnection-over-and-over/61032336#61032336)

Comment: `async/await` won't affect things here.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. The version og client and server lib did not match - Solved